# How do you check if two tags exists in a tag_map GROUP By article_id?

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, mariadb-10.5

In a fairly simple `tag_map`,

```
CREATE TABLE tag_map
(
article_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
tag_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(tag_id),
PRIMARY KEY(article_id,tag_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How can I check which articles have the pairs of tags given in this table?

```
 CREATE TABLE tag_pairs
(
pair_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
tag1 int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
tag2 int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX(tag1,tag2),
INDEX(tag2),
PRIMARY KEY(pair_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In the sample [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d5d2cecd9d4626b9ff2f7882fd6029ca), the intended output is:

```
SELECT article_id,pair_id FROM ... (how to JOIN here)

1    5
1    7
3    6
```

The efficiency is of utmost importance as the tables are quite big.

Since `tag_map` is quite big, I avoid `JOIN`in it to itself. Currently, I `SELECT` for each `pair_id`,

```
SELECT article_id, 5 
 FROM tag_map 
  WHERE tag_id IN(22,23) 
  GROUP BY article_id 
  HAVING SUM(IF(tag_id=22,1,0))>0 AND SUM(IF(tag_id=23,1,0))>0;
```

which is not efficient.

Comment: What happens if they have other pairs as well? Do they need both pairs or just one?

Comment: @Charlieface, we want all possible pairs, not one per article. Even two pairs of three tags. I update the example to show it.

Comment: Can you get rid of `pair_id`?  It seems useless since you could have `PRIMARY KEY(tag1, tag2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a variation of this one: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**. Read that question and the many (and different) ways to solve this interesting problem.

Surprisingly there is a much simpler solution to your more general problem - and it involves a triangular join:

```
select
    t1.article_id,
     p.pair_id
from 
    tag_map as t1
  join
    tag_map as t2
      on  t1.article_id = t2.article_id
  join
    tag_pairs as p
      on  p.tag1 = t1.tag_id
      and p.tag2 = t2.tag_id ;
```

Comment: I thought of something similar but hoped to open `tag_map` twice in the `JOIN`, as it is the large table. This is why I hoped to find a solution using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m1.article_id, m1.tag_id, m2.tag_id
    FROM tag_map AS m1
    JOIN tag_pairs AS p  ON p.tag1 = m1.tag_id
    JOIN tag_map AS m2   ON p.tag2 = m2.tag_id
    WHERE m2.article_id = m1.article_id;
```

and I changed tag_pairs to have

```
UNIQUE INDEX(pair_id),
INDEX(tag2),
PRIMARY KEY(tag1,tag2)
```

But I would rather get rid of pair_id completely.